# Complement a DataFrame with empty columns if it has a columns total lower than desired

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are some methods already published here to manually add a column, but my need is to add an amount that is still unknown.

So I currently use this method (the example, the total number of columns I need to have is 10, so it analyzes if there are 10 columns and if there are less than 10, it adds the rest needed):

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
cols = len(df.axes[1])
if cols < 10:
    for a in range(10-cols):
        dfclean = pd.DataFrame({'':['']})
        df = pd.concat([df, dfclean], axis=1)
        df = df.fillna('')
```

I believe this is not an intelligent and acceptable method, but it was the method that I managed to create from my current knowledge.

What is the correct method to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Does the column name need to be an empty string?, you could just do it in alphabetical format if you require always 10 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
alpha_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase[len(df.columns):10])
df[[alpha_list]] = None

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j
0  1  4  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
1  2  5  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
2  3  6  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
```

Changing the `None` to `""` works the same if you need that format.

---

Update to comment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
for i in range(len(df.columns),10):
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({"":[None,None,None]})],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  4  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
1  2  5  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
2  3  6  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
```

Works also putting `["","",""]` instead of `[None,None,None]`. These columns would just not be visible in VSCode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, yes the column name must be empty too.